# How can I store answers to questions then post to a database on submission

Tags: java, android, memory-management, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

This might be simple one but would help me massively, first let me explain what i am trying to do.

I want a user to register inside of my app and as part of this registration process I will need user to answers a series of questions where they basically fill out basic things like age, hobbies, career aspirations etc etc. Now I was wondering I've done a few light searches but haven't found anything on something I thought was simple, all I need to do is to store these answers in memory so that when they get to the final question when they submit the answers it basically posts the responses to a database that i have.

I'll show you some images and some code that I currently have.

[image]

[image]

Any help on the matter would be appreciated

It's basically 3 steps

1. User selects an answer
2. Users answers gets stored in memory
3. When user gets to final question push all answers to database

Comment: I would suggest when user clicks next you save that answer to database right away. But I guess you are trying to achieve a affect where when user does not go to final question nothing is saved. For that you can simply check if user answered all questions if not then remove those answers from database.

Comment: You should be aware that your question runs the risk of being downvoted/closed due to the lack of a specific question. You might want to edit it and ask a more direct question about the part you are struggling with. If it's advice on a best approach you're after you're better off Googling some more.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Data Class(Model class)
2. Declare that class instance in Activity scope
3. Store screen wise data into that instance(eg.name,address,etc.)
4. When you reach last fragment(last screen) then use this Data class

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use the ViewPager2 and navigation component to control the move between Fragments, and for each fragment you can use SharedPreference to store the values collected from the views i.e EditText or Drop Down

```
val sharedPref = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("onBoarding", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = sharedPref.edit()
editor.putString("text_captured", "NAME")
editor.apply
```

and then on the last Fragment you can receive all the values from the SharedPreference as shared below

```
val sharedPref = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences("MUCHBEER", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE) 
val receiveValue = sharedPref.getString("NAME")
```

Voila, now you will be good, Allow me to share the link [here](https://github.com/stevdza-san/ViewPager2-with-Navigation-Component-TestApp) for your guidance, If you will also be interested I can write code to observe the value entered using DataStore and DataBinding, please let me know.

Comment: please get in touch with me here: ryan@providencewebservices.co.uk